# Error while porting Python 2 script to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, compiler-errors, kivy

I'm trying to port a project from Python 2 to 3 but am getting stuck with some errors. The code runs without a problem under Python 2.7.8. The error is the following:

```
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\Simulator\simulator.pyw", line 2, in <module>
     from bin.ui.ui import start
   File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\Simulator\bin\ui\ui.py", line 30, in <module>
     import bin.global_variables as global_variables
   File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\Simulator\bin\global_variables.py", line 19, in <module>
     ANTIBIOTICS = {"Generic Antibiotic": Antibiotic("Generic Antibiotic")}
   File "C:\Users\DrPai\PycharmProjects\Simulator\bin\classes\Antibiotic.py", line 17, in __init__
     line_width=1.01)  # SmoothLinePlot
   File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\Simulator\bin\deps\kivy_graph\__init__.py", line 1031, in __init__
     super(Plot, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

The relevant part of the code that the error is pointing too are:

global_variables.py

```py
ANTIBIOTICS = {"Generic Antibiotic": Antibiotic("Generic Antibiotic")}
```

Antibiotic.py

```py
class Antibiotic(object):

    _total_antibiotics = 0  # int

    def __init__(self, name):

        self._id = 'ant' + str(Antibiotic._total_antibiotics)  # str
        self._name = name  # str
        self._line_color = hsv_to_rgb(*NewColor.new_color())  # (R,G,B)
        self._plot = SmoothLinePlot(points=[(0, 0)],
                                    color=self._line_color,
                                    line_width=1.01)  # SmoothLinePlot

        Antibiotic._total_antibiotics += 1
```

To draw the plots I'm relying on Kivy Graph widget accessible from here (https://github.com/kivy-garden/graph) and the error seems to be related to the code there:

__ init __.py

```py
class Plot(EventDispatcher):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Plot, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ask_draw = Clock.create_trigger(self.draw)
        self.bind(params=self.ask_draw, points=self.ask_draw)
        self._drawings = self.create_drawings()
```

Comment: I believe that `SmoothLinePlot` does not support `line_width`. If you remove `line_width` from the call to `SmoothLinePlot()`, do you still get the error?

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem and your suggestion solved it!

Comment: Glad you got a solution! However, for future info, your question is off-topic: It doesn't include the required [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Kivy graph doesn't support line_width and removal of it solves the problem.